# PHP foreach multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an multidimensional array like this:

```
Array
(
    [Category1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Img 1
                    [1] => Title 1
                    [2] => Text 1
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Img 17
                    [1] => Title 17
                    [2] => Text 5
                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Img 1
                    [1] => Title 6
                    [2] => Text 10
                )

            [16] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Img 16
                    [1] => Title 12
                    [2] => Text 16
                )

        )

    [Category2] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Img 2
                    [1] => Title 2
                    [2] => Text 2
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Img 18
                    [1] => Title 18
                    [2] => Text 6
                )

            [13] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Img 13
                    [1] => Title 9
                    [2] => Text 13
                )

        )

    [Category3] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Img 3
                    [1] => Title 3
                    [2] => Text 3
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Img 19
                    [1] => Title 19
                    [2] => Text 7
                )

            [11] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Img 11
                    [1] => Title 7
                    [2] => Text 11
                )

            [14] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Img 14
                    [1] => Title 10
                    [2] => Text 14
                )

        )

    [Category4] => Array
        (
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Img 4
                    [1] => Title 4
                    [2] => Text 4
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Img 20
                    [1] => Title 20
                    [2] => Text 8
                )

            [15] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Img 15
                    [1] => Title 11
                    [2] => Text 15
                )

        )

    [Category5] => Array
        (
            [9] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Img 9
                    [1] => Title 5
                    [2] => Text 9
                )

        )

    [Category6] => Array
        (
            [12] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Img 12
                    [1] => Title 8
                    [2] => Text 12
                )

        )

)
```

I need help to view like this, there $myarray is as on top example.
In the firs foreach all it's OK but in the sencond and the third foreach if i have more then one array at one category it is dublicated and displayed not corectly.

```
<div id="tab-container">
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($myarray as $category => $detail) { ?>
                <li><a href="#tab-<?=$category?>"><?=$category?></a></li>
            <?php }; ?>
        </ul>

    <div>
        <?php foreach (??? ??? ???) { ?>
            <div id="tab-<?=$category?> for ex Category 1 contain Array (1, 5 10, 16)">
                <div class="tab-content_left">
                    <div><img src="<?=base_url();?>img/$value[0] for ex Img 1" /></div>
                    <div>$value[1] for ex Title 1</div>
                    <div>$value[2] for ex Text 1</div>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-content_right">
                    <?php foreach (??? ??? ???) { ?>
                        <div><img src="<?=base_url();?>img/"$value[0] for ex Img 17 /></div>
                        <div>$value[1] for ex. Title 17</div>
                        <div>$value[2] for ex Text 5</div>
                    <?php }; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php }; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

THX. Please some ideas how can i put foreach cicles and where?

Comment: Just loop through the array twice.

Comment: I tray this but i confused with second and third foreach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First foreach:

```
<?php foreach ($mainArray as $categoryKey => $singleCategory) { ?>
```

Second foreach:

```
<?php foreach ($singleCategory as $categoryEntry) { ?>
```

**Note:**

To get the category name write `$categoryKey` in the first foreach.
To get data write: `$singleCategory['image']` inside the second foreach.

**Check [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) documentation.**

Comment: In my first foreach $categoryKey = Category_name and $singleCategory = array

Comment: THX Vlad. In the first and second foreach i need the same $singleCategory value from array, it work ok but if i have more items as the same category i can't display right. OK THX Vlad i weel try from begining.

Comment: You have every item in the category in the second foreach. That's the purpose of using a second foreach. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but it seems like you want the same content to be shown twice, which is not very good